# I am having troubles in C using chmod

Tags: c

I am having problems setting chmod mode to 620 or 640. I am trying to set the /dev/pts/# to crw--w---- to crw-r---- Here is my code.

```
long int mode;
char ttydev[13];
char yes[]="0640";
char no[]="0620";

        mode = strtol( yes, 0, 8 ); // compute the mode
        chmod( ttydev, mode ); // change the mode of the file
        //chmod(ttydev, S_ISUID|S_IRWXU|S_IWGRP|S_IWUSR|S_IWOTH);
        printf("%s%s%s%lu\n","ttydev= ", ttydev, "mode= ", mode);
```

If I do it manually entering chmod 640 /dev/pts/# it works fine.

Comment: What's the return value from `chmod()`?  I tried your code on a regular file and it worked.

Comment: Can you show what the printf displays?

Comment: Way off-topic, but  `printf( "ttydev=%s mode=%ld\n", ttydev, mode );`

Comment: Also off-topic. C has octal literals; you could just write `int yes = 0640;`.

Comment: Have you left out the code that initializes `ttydev`, or is it just used uninitialized?

Comment: Who owns /dev/pts/# - do you actually have sufficient privileges to change it? Did you have to sudo when you did it manually?